# How do I query data from the database base on user in a completely separated frontend Django REST

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

So I have this basic model:

```
class Text(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title
```

so usually when you're using regular Django and you want to query `Text` from the database based on the user you would do:

```
def main_page(request):

    userTexts = Text.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    context = {}
    return render(request, '', context)
```

but now I've been using Django REST React stack and built a completely separated frontend and the only way I access the data from the backend is by making HTTP request to it, so now `request.user` wont work anymore because it's just going to return `anonymousUser`

fortunately though I already have an authentication system working and already have a user object inside my react state all I have to do is design a view and an API call to query the data from the backend
but I cant imagine how to do both of those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, here is no matter how you try to access backend URL, directly inserting it in browser bar or using React's xhr.

You just need to set session cookies for backend URL (`domain.com:port`) that is [not accessible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) by javascript in perfect world:

> A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript
> Document.cookie API; it is sent only to the server. For example,
> cookies that persist server-side sessions don't need to be available
> to JavaScript, and should have the HttpOnly attribute. This precaution
> helps mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

`anonymousUser` means that [session cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions) is not set and authentication (login) process didn't complete.
Why it happens? I don't know, it depends on backend architecture, login process details, etc...

And don't forget to set proper CORS policies if frontend's and backend's `domain.com:port` are different.